# Cannot GET /api/cars/

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I make an app with React, Redux. MongoDB and Express.

I have page with table of all cars. My idea is to show them in the table and I want to create, edit and delete cars. But when I click on the button Create or Edit , the browser's console says me "Cannot GET /api/cars/646dd9e9b33ecd08d9353605".

I searched a lot , where is problem , but i don't find it. Can you help me , please?

I show the code :

**CarListScreen.js**

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useReducer } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link, useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

import { Store } from '../Store';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';
import { getError } from '../utils';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';


const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_REQUEST':
      return { ...state, loading: true };
    case 'FETCH_SUCCESS':
      return {
        ...state,
        cars: action.payload.cars,
        page: action.payload.page,
        pages: action.payload.pages,
        loading: false,
      };
    case 'FETCH_FAIL':
      return { ...state, loading: false, error: action.payload };
    case 'CREATE_REQUEST':
      return { ...state, loadingCreate: true };
    case 'CREATE_SUCCESS':
      return {
        ...state,
        loadingCreate: false,
      };
    case 'CREATE_FAIL':
      return { ...state, loadingCreate: false };
      case 'DELETE_REQUEST':
        return { ...state, loadingDelete: true, successDelete: false, };
      case 'DELETE_SUCCESS':
        return {
          ...state,
          loadingDelete: false,
          successDelete: true,
        };
      case 'DELETE_FAIL':
        return { ...state, loadingDelete: false, successDelete: false, };
        case 'DELETE_RESET':
          return { ...state, loadingDelete: false, successDelete: false, };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default function CarListScreen() {
  const [
    {
      loading,
      error,
      cars,
      pages,
      loadingCreate,
      loadingDelete,
      successDelete
    },
    dispatch,
  ] = useReducer(reducer, {
    loading: true,
    error: '',
  });

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { search } = useLocation();
  const sp = new URLSearchParams(search);
  const page = sp.get('page') || 1;

  const { state } = useContext(Store);
  const { userInfo } = state;

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/cars/admin?page=${page} `, {
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
        });

        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: data });
      } catch (err) {}
    };
  
    if(successDelete){
      dispatch({type: 'DELETE_RESET'});
    } else {
      fetchData();
    }
   
  }, [page, userInfo, successDelete]);

  const createHandler = async () => {
    if (window.confirm('Are you sure to create?')) {
      try {
        dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_REQUEST' });
        const { data } = await axios.post(
          '/api/cars',
          {},
          {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
          }
        );
        toast.success('car created successfully');
        dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_SUCCESS' });
        navigate(`/admin/car/${data.car._id}`);
      } catch (err) {
        toast.error(getError(error));
        dispatch({
          type: 'CREATE_FAIL',
        });
      }
    }
  };

  const deleteHandler = async (car) => {
    if(window.confirm('Are you sure to delete?')) {
      try{
        await axios.delete(`/api/cars/${car._id}`, {
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`},
        });
        toast.success('product deleted successfully');
        dispatch({type: 'DELETE_SUCCESS'});
      }catch(err){
        toast.error(getError(error));
        dispatch({
          type: 'DELETE_FAIL',
        });
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <h1>Cars</h1>
        </Col>
        <Col className="col text-end">
          <div>
            <Button type="button" onClick={createHandler}>
              Create Car
            </Button>
          </div>
        </Col>
      </Row>

      {loadingCreate && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}
      {loadingDelete && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}

      {loading ? (
        <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
      ) : error ? (
        <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
      ) : (
        <>
          <table className="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>MARK</th>
                <th>MODEL</th>
                <th>CATEGORY</th>
                <th>PRICE PER DAY</th>
                <th>PRICE PER HOUR</th>
                <th>ACTIONS</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {cars.map((car) => (
                <tr key={car._id}>
                  <td>{car._id}</td>
                  <td>{car.mark}</td>
                  <td>{car.model}</td>
                  <td>{car.category}</td>
                  <td>{car.pricePerHour}</td>
                  <td>{car.pricePerDay}</td>
                  <td>
                    <Button
                      type="button"
                      variant="light"
                      onClick={() => navigate(`/admin/car/${car._id}`)}
                    >
                      Edit
                    </Button>
                    &nbsp;
                    &nbsp;
                    <Button
                      type="button"
                      variant="light"
                      onClick={()=> deleteHandler(car)}
                    >
                      Delete
                    </Button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <div>
            {[...Array(pages).keys()].map((x) => (
              <Link
                className={x + 1 === Number(page) ? 'btn text-bold' : 'btn'}
                key={x + 1}
                to={`/admin/cars?page=${x + 1}`}
              >
                {x + 1}
              </Link>
            ))}
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**CarEditScreen.js**

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useReducer, useState } from 'react'
import { Store } from '../Store';
import { getError } from '../utils';
import {toast} from 'react-toastify'
import axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet-async';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';


const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_REQUEST':
            return {...state, loading:true};
        case 'FETCH_SUCCESS':
            return {...state, loading:false};
        case 'FETCH_FAIL':
            return {...state, loading:false};
        case 'UPDATE_REQUEST':
                return {...state, loadingUpdate:true};
        case 'UPDATE_SUCCESS':
                return {...state, loadingUpdate:false};
        case 'UPDATE_FAIL':
                return {...state, loadingUpdate:false};
        default: return state;
    }
};

export default function CarEditScreen() {

    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const params = useParams();
    const {id:carId} = params;
    const {state} = useContext(Store);
    const {userInfo} = state;
    const [{loading, error, loadingUpdate}, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
        loading: true,
        error: '',
    });

    const [mark, setMark] = useState('');
    const [model, setModel] = useState('');
    const [year, setYear] = useState('');
    const [fuelType, setFuelType] = useState('');
    const [transmission, setTransmission] = useState('');
    const [capacity, setCapacity] = useState('');
    const [pricePerDay, setPricePerDay] = useState('');
    const [pricePerHour, setPricePerHour] = useState('');
    const [image, setImage] = useState('');
    const [category, setCategory] = useState('');
    const [avaliable, setAvaliable] = useState('');
    const [description, setDescription] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try{
                dispatch({type: 'FETCH_REQUEST'});
                const {data} = await axios.get(`/api/cars/${carId}`);
                setMark(data.mark);
                setModel(data.model);
                setYear(data.year);
                setFuelType(data.fuelType);
                setTransmission(data.transmission);
                setCapacity(data.capacity);
                setPricePerDay(data.pricePerDay);
                setPricePerHour(data.procePerHour);
                setImage(data.image);
                setCategory(data.category);
                setAvaliable(data.avaliable);
                setDescription(data.description);
                dispatch({type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS'});


            }catch(err) {
                dispatch({
                    type: 'FETCH_FAIL',
                    payload: getError(err),
                });
            }
        };
        fetchData();
    }, [carId]);

    const submitHandler = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try{
            dispatch({type: 'UPDATE_REQUEST'});
            await axios.put(
                `/api/cars/${carId}`,
                {
                    _id: carId,
                    mark,
                    model,
                    year,
                    fuelType,
                    capacity,
                    transmission,
                    pricePerDay,
                    pricePerHour,
                    image,
                    category,
                    avaliable,
                    description
                },
                {
                    headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`},
                }
            );
            dispatch({
                type: 'UPDATE_SUCCESS',
            });
            toast.success('Product updated successfully');

        }catch(err){
           toast.error(getError(err));
           navigate('/admin/cars');
        }
    }

  return (
    <Container className='small-container'>
        <Helmet>
            <title>Edit Car ${carId}</title>
        </Helmet>
        <h2>Edit Car {carId}</h2>

        {loading ? (
            <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
        ) : error ? (
            <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
        ) : (
            <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="mark">
                    <Form.Label>Mark</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                    value={mark}
                    onChange={(e)=> setMark(e.target.value)}
                    required
                    />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="model">
                    <Form.Label>Model</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                    value={model}
                    onChange={(e)=> setModel(e.target.value)}
                    required
                    />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="year">
                    <Form.Label>Year</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                    value={year}
                    onChange={(e)=> setYear(e.target.value)}
                    required
                    />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="fuelType">
                    <Form.Label>Fuel Type</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                    value={fuelType}
                    onChange={(e)=> setFuelType(e.target.value)}
                    required
                    />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="transmission">
                    <Form.Label>Transmission</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                    value={transmission}
                    onChange={(e)=> setTransmission(e.target.value)}
                    required
                    />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="capacity">
                    <Form.Label>Capacity</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                    value={capacity}
                    onChange={(e)=> setCapacity(e.target.value)}
                    required
                    />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="pricePerDay">
                    <Form.Label>Price Per Day</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                    value={pricePerDay}
                    onChange={(e)=> setPricePerDay(e.target.value)}
                    required
                    />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="pricePerHour">
                    <Form.Label>Price Per Hour</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                    value={pricePerHour}
                    onChange={(e)=> setPricePerHour(e.target.value)}
                    required
                    />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="image">
                    <Form.Label>Image</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                    value={image}
                    onChange={(e)=> setImage(e.target.value)}
                    required
                    />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="category">
                    <Form.Label>Category</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                    value={category}
                    onChange={(e)=> setCategory(e.target.value)}
                    required
                    />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="avaliable">
                    <Form.Label>Avaliable</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                    value={avaliable}
                    onChange={(e)=> setAvaliable(e.target.value)}
                    required
                    />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="description">
                    <Form.Label>Desription</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                    value={description}
                    onChange={(e)=> setDescription(e.target.value)}
                    required
                    />
                </Form.Group>
                <div className='mb-3'>
                    <Button disabled={loadingUpdate} type="submit">Update</Button>
                    {loadingUpdate && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}
                </div>
            </Form>
        )
    }
    </Container>
  )
}
```

**carRoutes.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import Car from '../models/carModel.js';
import expressAsyncHandler from 'express-async-handler';
import { isAuth, isAdmin } from '../utils.js';

const carRouter = express.Router();

carRouter.get('/', async (req,res)=>{
    const cars = await Car.find();
    res.send(cars);
});

carRouter.post('/', isAuth, expressAsyncHandler(async (req,res)=> {
  const newCar = new Car({
        mark: 'sample name' + Date.now(),
        model: 'sample name' + Date.now(),
        year: 0,
        category: 'sample category',
        capacity: 0,
        fuelType: 'sample name',
        transmission: 'sample name',
        image: '/images/p1.jpg',
        pricePerHour: 0,
        pricePerDay: 0,
        available: true,
        description: 'sample description',
  });
  const car = await newCar.save();
  res.send({message: 'Car created', car});
})
);

    carRouter.put(
        '/:id',
        isAuth,
        expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
          const carId = req.params.id;
          const car = await Car.findById(carId);
          if (car) {
            car.mark = req.body.mark;
            car.model = req.body.model;
            car.year = req.body.year;
            car.capacity = req.body.capacity;
            car.fuelType = req.body.fuelType;
            car.transmission = req.body.transmission;
            car.pricePerDay = req.body.pricePerDay;
            car.pricePerHour = req.body.pricePerHour;
            car.image = req.body.image;
            car.category = req.body.category;
            car.available = req.body.available;
            car.description = req.body.description;
            await car.save();
            res.send({ message: 'Car Updated' });
          } else {
            res.status(404).send({ message: 'Car Not Found' });
          }
        })
      );

      carRouter.delete(
        '/:id',
        isAuth,
        expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
          const car = await Car.findById(req.params.id);
          if (car) {
            await car.deleteOne();
            res.send({ message: 'Car Deleted' });
          } else {
            res.status(404).send({ message: 'Car Not Found' });
          }
        })
      );


const PAGE_SIZE = 3;

carRouter.get(
    '/admin',
    isAuth , expressAsyncHandler(async (req,res)=>{
        const {query} = req;
        const page = query.page || 1 ;
        const pageSize = query.pageSize || PAGE_SIZE;

        const cars = await Car.find()
        .skip(pageSize * (page - 1))
        .limit(pageSize);
        const countCars = await Car.countDocuments();
        res.send({
            cars,
            countCars,
            page,
            pages: Math.ceil(countCars / pageSize),
        })
    })
)

carRouter.get('/model/:model', async (req,res)=>{
    const car = await Car.findOne({model: req.params.model});
    if(car){
        res.send(car);
    }else{
        res.status(404).send({message: 'Car Not Found'});
    }
});



export default carRouter;
```

**App.js**

```
import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import {ToastContainer} from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css'
import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";
import CarScreen from './screens/CarScreen';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import NavDropdown from 'react-bootstrap/NavDropdown';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import {LinkContainer} from 'react-router-bootstrap';
import SigninScreen from './screens/SigninScreen';
import { Store } from './Store';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import PersonalDataScreen from './screens/PersonalDataScreen';
import SignupScreen from './screens/SignupScreen.';
import PaymentMethodScreen from './screens/PaymentMethodScreen';
import PlaceOrderScreen from './screens/PlaceOrderScreen';
import ProfileScreen from './screens/ProfileScreen';
import ProtectedRoute from './components/ProtectedRoute';
import DashboardScreen from './screens/DashboardScreen';
import AdminRoute from './components/AdminRoute';
import CarListScreen from './screens/CarListScreen';
import CarEditScreen from './screens/CarEditScreen';
import UserListScreen from './screens/UserListScreen';
import UserEditScreen from './screens/UserEditScreen';
import SearchBox from './components/SearchBox';
import CartScreen from './screens/CartScreen';
import Badge from 'react-bootstrap/esm/Badge';

function App() {
  const {state, dispatch: ctxDispatch} = useContext(Store)
  const {cart, userInfo} = state;

  const signoutHandler = () =>{
    ctxDispatch({type: 'USER_SIGNOUT'});
    localStorage.removeItem('userInfo');
    localStorage.removeItem('personalData');
    localStorage.removeItem('paymentMethod');
    window.location.href= '/signin';
  };


  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        
          <ToastContainer position="botton-center" limit={1} />
          <header>
            <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
              <Container>
               
                <LinkContainer to="/">
                  <Navbar.Brand>carRental</Navbar.Brand>
                </LinkContainer>
                <SearchBox />
                <Nav className='me-auto'>
                    <Link to="/cart" className='nav-link'>
                      Reservations
                      {cart.cartItems.length > 0 && (
                        <Badge pill bg="danger">
                          {cart.cartItems.length}
                          
                        </Badge>
                      )}
                      </Link>
                </Nav>
                <Nav className="me-auto">
                  {userInfo ? (
                    <NavDropdown title={userInfo.name} id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                      <LinkContainer to="/profile">
                        <NavDropdown.Item>User Profile</NavDropdown.Item>
                      </LinkContainer>
                      <LinkContainer to="/orderhistory">
                        <NavDropdown.Item>Order History</NavDropdown.Item>
                      </LinkContainer>
                      <NavDropdown.Divider />
                      <Link className='dropdown-item' to="#signout" onClick={signoutHandler}>Sign out</Link>

                    </NavDropdown>
                  ):(
                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/signin">
                    Sign In
                    </Link>
                  )}

                  {userInfo && userInfo.isAdmin && (
                    <NavDropdown title="Admin" id="admin-nav-dropdown">
                      <LinkContainer to="/admin/dashboard">
                        <NavDropdown.Item>Dashboard</NavDropdown.Item>
                      </LinkContainer>
                      <LinkContainer to="/admin/cars">
                        <NavDropdown.Item>Cars</NavDropdown.Item>
                      </LinkContainer>
                      <LinkContainer to="/admin/order">
                        <NavDropdown.Item>Orders</NavDropdown.Item>
                      </LinkContainer>
                      <LinkContainer to="/admin/users">
                        <NavDropdown.Item>Users</NavDropdown.Item>
                      </LinkContainer>
                    </NavDropdown>
                  )}
                </Nav>
              </Container>
            </Navbar>
          </header>
          <main>
            <Container className='mt-3'>
              <Routes>
                <Route path="/car/:model" element={<CarScreen />} />
                <Route path="/signin" element={<SigninScreen />} />
                <Route path="/signup" element={<SignupScreen />} />
                <Route path="/profile" element={
                <ProtectedRoute>
                  <ProfileScreen />
                </ProtectedRoute>} />
                <Route path="/personalData" element={<PersonalDataScreen />} />
                <Route path="/payment" element={<PaymentMethodScreen />} />
                {/* Admin routes */}
                <Route path="/admin/dashboard" 
                element={<AdminRoute><DashboardScreen /></AdminRoute>}></Route> 
                  <Route path="/admin/cars" 
                element={<AdminRoute><CarListScreen /></AdminRoute>}></Route> 
                <Route path="/admin/car/:id" 
                element={<AdminRoute><CarEditScreen /></AdminRoute>}></Route> 

                <Route path="/admin/user/:id" 
                element={<AdminRoute><UserEditScreen /></AdminRoute>}></Route> 
                 <Route path="/admin/users" 
                element={<AdminRoute><UserListScreen /></AdminRoute>}></Route> 
                <Route path="/placeorder" element={<PlaceOrderScreen />} />
                <Route path="/cart" element={<CartScreen />} />
                <Route path="/" element={<HomeScreen />} />
              </Routes>   
            </Container>        
          </main>
          <footer>
            <div className="text-center">All rights reserved</div>
          </footer>
       
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Just FYI, the `useReducer` hook has nothing at all to do with Redux. Their similarity ends at "dispatch actions to update a state machine via reducer functions". Based on the error message it looks possibly like an issue with the GET call to the backend made from the `CarEditScreen` component. Is there more to the error message that might help indicate better where the issue is occurring? Have you checked the network tab in the frontend or the backend server logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GET endpoint for "api/cars/:carid" is missing in the carRoutes.js file. Please add the GET endpoint there and it will work.

Comment: Thank you , I added GET endpoint and It just goes ready.